# How to add a placeholder for $oid in @Query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document '`col`' , which is ObjectId type. I need to pass ObjectId value to `findData(String objId)` and add a placeholder for objId. But It doesnt works?

```
@Query("{'col' : { '$oid' : ?0}}")
public List<Datas> findData(String objId);
```

How to add a placeholder for `$oid` type?

Answer (score 0):

Its by a mistake. The problem here is that the placeholder is for ObjectId of MongoDB and , the passed value was in String type.  The below code solved the problem

```
@Query("{'col' : { '$oid' : ?0}}")
public List<Datas> findData(ObjectId objId);
```